# Numpy: split array randomly

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape holding many (200 in this example) monochromatic 64x64 pixel images, thus having the shape:

```
>>> a.shape
(200L, 1L, 64L, 64L)
```

I want to split these images in 3 new arrays, `a1`, `a2`, `a3` where they will contain 80%, 10%, 10% of the images respectively, and I am doing it in the following way (I do not want them to be consecutive in `a`):

```
import numpy as np
import random

a = --read images from file--

a1 = numpy.empty((0,1,64,64))
a2 = numpy.empty((0,1,64,64))
a3 = numpy.empty((0,1,64,64))

for i in range(200): #200 is the number of images
    temp = a[-1]
    a = np.delete(a,-1,0)
    rand = random.random()
    if rand < 0.8:
        a1 = np.append(a1,[temp],0)
    elsif rand < 0.9:
        a2 = np.append(a2,[temp],0)
    else:
        a3 = np.append(a3,[temp],0)
```

I try to emulate `pop` and `append` which are done at `O(1)` time on lists, but does the same hold for numpy arrays?
Is there some way to do this more efficiently (faster) for a large number (thousands) of images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a one-liner using [`np.vsplit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vsplit.html) -

```
a1,a2,a3 = np.vsplit(a[np.random.permutation(a.shape[0])],(160,180))
```

1) Shape check :

```
In [205]: a = np.random.rand(200,1,64,64)

In [206]: a1,a2,a3 = np.vsplit(a[np.random.permutation(a.shape[0])],(160,180))

In [207]: a.shape
Out[207]: (200, 1, 64, 64)

In [208]: a1.shape
Out[208]: (160, 1, 64, 64)

In [209]: a2.shape
Out[209]: (20, 1, 64, 64)

In [210]: a3.shape
Out[210]: (20, 1, 64, 64)
```

2) Value check on a toy data to make sure we are picking random images and not consecutive ones for splitting :

```
In [212]: a
Out[212]: 
array([[5, 8, 4],
       [7, 7, 6],
       [3, 2, 7],
       [1, 4, 8],
       [4, 1, 0],
       [2, 1, 3],
       [6, 5, 2],
       [2, 4, 5],
       [6, 6, 5],
       [5, 2, 5]])

In [213]: a1,a2,a3 = np.vsplit(a[np.random.permutation(a.shape[0])],(6,8))

In [214]: a1
Out[214]: 
array([[1, 4, 8],
       [7, 7, 6],
       [6, 6, 5],
       [2, 4, 5],
       [4, 1, 0],
       [5, 2, 5]])

In [215]: a2
Out[215]: 
array([[3, 2, 7],
       [2, 1, 3]])

In [216]: a3
Out[216]: 
array([[6, 5, 2],
       [5, 8, 4]])
```

Comment: Nice, simple solution, thanks! Seems fast enough with O(n) complexity in my simple tests. Btw, I know that it was not in my original question but what about the memory? This ends up with both `a` and the split pieces in memory, is there a way to do this without replicating `a`?