# Divide pandas DataFrame rows in specific number of random sets

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I would like to divide the rows of a DataFrame in 5 sets randomly. They don't have to be of the same size. Any ideas?

Comment: this is a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974630/numpy-split-array-randomly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could form a list of sub-DataFrames by assigning a group number to each row and then grouping by that number:

```
import numpy as np
num_groups = 5
df['group'] = np.random.randint(num_groups, size=len(df))
dfs = [grp for key, grp in df.groupby('group')]
```

---

If you do not wish to add a `group` column to the original DataFrame, you could instead use

```
import numpy as np
num_groups = 5
dfs = [grp for key, grp in df.groupby(np.random.randint(num_groups, size=len(df)))]
```

Comment: Thank you unutbu. Your answer is great!